# "md-chips-select" not bind data from http request

Tags: angularjs, md-chip

I use an "[md-chips-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-chips-select)" npm module in my project. It's working perfectly when i bind static data like :

```
$scope.listItems = [{ name: "Mini Cooper", id: 0 }, { name: "Lexus IS250", id: 1 }, { name: "Ford F150", id: 2 }, { name: "Toyota Prius", id: 3 }];






<md-chips-select ng-model="selectedItems" select-items="listItems" main-title="name"></md-chips-select>
```

but when i load data from http request it's not working.

```
$scope.listItems = [];
        Section.get()
            .success(function(data) {
                if(data){
                        _.each(data ,function (_jsonObject) {
                            var _c = _jsonObject.Class + "-" + _jsonObject.Section;
                            var _json = { name : _c, id : _jsonObject._id };
                            $scope.listItems.push(_json);
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: are you sure that your loop works correctly?

Comment: ya i'm sure. Now i use 'ngTagsInput' http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/ Thanks for your comment

Comment: and this solved your problem?

Comment: Ya the 'ngTagsInput' works perfect to me.